# Entity Framework DB Not updating until project is rebuilt?

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework

My project uses LINQ to SQL and EF to handle objects in the database. I have a status column in an entity object that is designated as an int. My BI layer updates this data with the below code, when i change the data, if i query SQL i see the updated value in the DB, however the UI layer is not displaying the new value, it shows the old one. Stopping the project in VS and re-starting it, then it will display the updated data.

Does EF do any caching? Could this be caused by having 3 seperate projects for Data, UI and BI?

```
Public Shared Function UpdateStatus(PersonID As Guid, Status As LeadStatus, UserName As String) As Boolean
    Dim db As New MyDb.DBContainer
    Dim z = (From p In db.People Where p.Id = PersonID).FirstOrDefault()
    If Not IsNothing(z) Then
        z.Status = Status
        db.SaveChanges()
        LeadLogFunctions.AddLog(LeadLogTypes.StatusChanged, PersonID, UserName, "Status Changed By: " & UserName & " To: " & Enumeration.GetEnumDescription(Status))
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The UI layer won't display the new value until you reload it from the database.

If you are keeping the same `DbContext` open, you should reload the existing entity rather than making a new query using the `DbContext.Entry(of T)().Reload()` function.

Comment: I have a wrapper class that accesses the entity. Such that i make some call say New Person(PersonID) that access the DBContext, should i have that class .Reload each time it is initialized?